# Builtin PHP function to serialize structured array into hidden fields

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a function that will convert this array:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["b"]=>
    int(1)
    ["c"]=>
    string(5) "hello"
  }
}
```

into something like:

```
array(2) {
  ["a[b]"]=>
  int(1)
  ["a[c]"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
}
```

I.e. to "serialize" structured array so that I can easily put it to HTML form as hidden fields and when I read it back from the `$_POST`, I get exactly the same structure! Is there any PHP built-in function for that?

Comment: Nope, while PHP is pretty rich in functions for most things, that you'll have to code yourself

Comment: Isn't [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) an option?

Comment: Thanks @Mark.. are there any similar useful functions that can help in the task?

Comment: Something like a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849021/generate-a-custom-html-form-using-array-values-with-php ?

Comment: Or using serialize/unserialize with just one input field – if you don’t need the data client-side for access to the single values. Or, if you don’t need it client-side, why not put it into the session in the first place and avoid the round-trip to the client?

Comment: @CBroe - robustness. Sessions are evil. My forms never expire :-)

Comment: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or  [msgpack_pack](http://msgpack.org/) would go a good job but if you want pure PHP try [Rison](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Rison)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to flatten it yourself. There's in no built-in one-line function that could do that.

```
function flattenArr($arr, $key, &$result) {
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            flattenArr($v, $key . "[$k]", $result);
        } else {
            $result[$key . "[$k]"] = $v;
        }
    }
}

$obj = array("a" => array("b" => "c", "d" => array("1"=>array(1,2,3,5),"2", "3")));
$result = array();
flattenArr($obj, "", $result);
foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    echo "result$k = $v\n";
}
```

OUTPUTS:

```
result[a][b] = c
result[a][d][1][0] = 1
result[a][d][1][1] = 2
result[a][d][1][2] = 3
result[a][d][1][3] = 5
result[a][d][2] = 2
result[a][d][3] = 3
```

This might not work out the way it is now, you will probably have to modify it a bit. HTH

Comment: What happens with objects ?

Comment: The answer was just to give the OP an idea. If OP wants to deal with objects, he will have to induce relevant changes.

Comment: @Baba Out of curiosity, when/where were objects mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Jon the OP does not know it yet ... he would be back when he realize how json has made his live easier

Comment: @Baba then OP should make objects that overload the `__toString()` method appropriately if needed in form data. =P lol

Comment: @Baba: Yes, the `go(..)` function can very well be avoided. It originally had more content which I later backspaced it out. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Tomas asked for the first level array not to set [].

Comment: @Svetlio, that's fine - I prefer to keep this solution as simple as it is now!

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(
        "a"=> array( "b"=>1, "c"=>"hello", "d"=> array( "e"=>3, "j"=>"wow") ),
        "z"  => array( "za"=>22, "tt"=>'wos')
    );

function loop_it($array, $arr=array(), $Mkey = false){
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $_key = $Mkey ? $Mkey . "[" . $key . "]" : $key;
        if(is_array($value)){
            $arr += loop_it($value, $arr, $_key);
        } else{
            $arr[$_key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

$return = loop_it($arr);    
var_dump($return);
```

Here is working function ..:)